# WebRTC javascript on website and opentok on IOS connectivity

Tags: webrtc, opentok

We are using WebRTC jingle on our website and now we want to use OpenTok in IOS app. Is it possible to connect these two?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenTok mobile SDKs are only designed to work with web clients that also use the OpenTok JS SDK. My suggestion is to just use the OpenTok JavaScript SDK for your site. If there are some features missing or something you need in addition, let me or anyone else at TokBox know.